# How to debug TestNG listener with Intellij IDEA using Maven configuration

Tags: java, maven, debugging, intellij-idea, testng

I am using Intellij IDEA and I need to debug some method in a TestNG listener.

In the Run/Debug Configurations, I added a Maven command.
I set the break point, and clicked the Debug button and it just passed the break point (as if I just clicked Play).

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to run TestNG with maven ? IntelliJ is able to do it itself.

Comment: @JulienHerr because I want to run the whole suite (not a specific test) and debug a method that is located in "onExecutionFinish" of the suite.

Comment: IntelliJ is able to run a suite file or many classes too. It could be a good start.

Comment: @JulienHerr thanks. Just ran the suit.xml with Debug.

Comment: Yep, you get it ! It is possible to run mvnDebug if you can't reproduce something but it a bit more complicate.

Comment: Did you register your listener? If you add logging instead of trying to debug does it get logged? My guess is that your listener isn't registered and it is not executing. I recommend trying to add logging before trying to use a debugger.

Comment: @mfulton26 thanks. can you please explain, what you mean by registered?

Comment: See the subsections to [5.17 - TestNG Listeners](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners).